# Best approach to extend classes but use a specific method as entrypoint for super class

Tags: python, overloading, super

So I'm looking into having a main class that defines a specific method and an extended class that adds some functionality to that method, such as:

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _get_obj(self, id):
        pass

    def get(self,  obj_id):
        # do stuff that should be done for all methods, eg.
        if obj_id not in self.data:
            obj= self._get_obj(obj_id)
            self.data[obj_id] = obj              
        return self.data[obj_id]

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def _get_obj(self, obj_id):
        pass
```

The idea is that the `get` method is the only "public" one. Is there a better way to do this?
For clarity I've only shown one of the "public" methods, but there may be many.

For reference, this is using Python 3.6. And any other comments regarding the code are welcome.

Update (also code cleanup): Another approach is to use `super` to call the original `get` which may be clearer, but forces the coder to always need to add the call there:

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}

    def get(self,  obj_id):
        # do stuff that should be done for all methods, eg.
        if obj_id in self.data:
            return self.data[obj_id]
        pass                


class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def get_from_db(self, obj_id):
        # Code to get from db
        return obj

    def get(self, obj_id):
        obj = super().get(obj_id
        if None:
            obj= self.get_from_db(obj_id)
            self.data[obj_id] = obj  
        return obj
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Your getters and setters seem irrelevant, but in any case I can't understand what the question is - what doesn't work with this code?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables.

Comment: I think this code is perfectly fine as-is (assuming the getter/setter for `data` actually does something useful). The only thing that looks like bad design to me is how you're taking `*args` and `**kwargs` just to throw them away.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The getters/setters are just to check if there is something wrong with the approach.
The code works fine as is, but I was trying to figure out if there was a better way to call `get` outside of these classes, by using `super` or some other approach.


@Rawing Thanks. The `args` and `kwargs` are indeed relevant in this example (in the actual code, I use them)

Comment: I still don't know what  you mean by "call get outside of these classes", and what `super` has to do with it. If you want to call get, just do so: `my_sub_class.get(whatever)`.